# A few questions about limits and also continuity

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a test tomorrow and I've been studying for most of the week (including last) and I just want some clarification on a few things. If you guys can help that would be fantastic.

So looking at this problem,

Limit : $x \rightarrow 0$

$$\frac{\frac{3}{x+3} - 1}{x} $$

If I were to do it by simply plugging it in, I would get $3/3 - 1$ which is $0$ and the denominator would obviously also be $0$ so the final answer would be $0/0$.

Now if I didn't want this answer, couldn't I just use $.001$ to find the limit instead?

I believe the answer when I do it this way is $-.33$

Can I just do this for all limits? Is this even the correct way to approach this problem?

Lastly, can someone clarify when a limit is continuous at $x = c$?

I believe that there are 3 parameters and I can only recall two currently.

Comment: If you bring the top to the common denominator $x+3$, then the top becomes $\frac{-x}{x+3}$. So our full expression is $\frac{-x}{x(x+3)}$. Cancel the $x$'s, and let $x$ approach $0$.

Comment: Using values close to $a$ will give you a decent idea of what $f(x)$ is as $x \rightarrow a$, and is probably a way to check your work, but it's definitely not a way to determine the limit, and won't help you when the limit is a complicated value.

Answer (score 1):

The final answer wouldn't be $\frac{0}{0}$, since that's undefined. You'd have to algebraically manipulate it in order to avoid the $\frac{0}{0}$ scenario. In your example above, simplifying the numerator, allows you to cancel with the denominator. $\dfrac{\frac{3}{x+3}-1}{x}=\dfrac{\frac{3}{x+3}-\frac{x+3}{x+3}}{x}=\dfrac{-\frac{x}{x+3}}{x}=-\dfrac{1}{x+3}$. After simplifying the expression, now evaluating this as $x\to 0$ is no problem.

You can't just substitute $-0.33$, since that's not close enough to $0$, but regardless of what value you choose that you consider close to $0$, I can always choose a number that's closer to $0$, so substituting values close to the limit numerically won't work.

---

A function $f(x)$ is said to be continuous at $x=c$ if:

- $\lim_{x\to c^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^+} f(x)$ (This means that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists.)
- $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=f(c)$

Comment: well no what I did was substitute .001 instead and THEN my value would be -.33 but I understand what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: @METEORITES: Yes, I misread, but the same principle applies even with $0.001$.

Comment: Well see here is the only qualm I have. By using .001, we got the same answer, since -1/3 is -.333333333.  I suppose that it is not at all a superior method to accomplish this, however do you think it might do to approximate?

Comment: @METEORITES: It sort of approximates it, but your answer will always be more precise if you work it out algebraically. For example, I just plugged in $0.001$ and got $-0.33322225924691769410196601132956$, but we know that our algebraic solution was $-\frac{1}{3}=-0.33333333333333333333\ldots$, so although it seems accurate at first, as we look at more decimal places, we see that the algebraic solution is more accurate.

Comment: AH! I see, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{3}{x+3}-1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{3-x-3}{x+3}}{x}= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{x}{x+3}}{x} $$
$$= \lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{x}{x(x+3)} = \lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{1}{x+3} = -\frac{1}{0+3} =-\frac{1}{3}$$